# Clientside XSLT in Mozilla/Firefox fails

Tags: xslt

I have a result document that renders in Chrome, but not Mozilla/Firefox.

I *believe* it is because there is top level leading whitespace (two blank lines before the `<!DOCTYPE html`).

How can I change this transform to not have leading whitespace ([fiddle](http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHUq/2))?

XML:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="/css/my.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<webpage>
    <title>Book</title>
    <auth>Mike</auth>
    <container-content>
        <p>foo1</p>
        <p>foo2</p>    
    </container-content>
</webpage>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output 
        method="xml" 
        indent="yes"
        encoding="UTF-8"
        omit-xml-declaration="yes"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" 
        doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" 
                     content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>                
                </head>            
                <body>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="//container-content/*"/>
                </body>
            </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
- a blank line here -
- and here -
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>foo1</p>
        <p>foo2</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

*Alternatively*, I may be incorrect, and the two blank lines are not the cause of the failed render in Mozilla/Firefox. I have a hard time troubleshooting client side transforms.

**Side note:** I've developed in Saxon 6.5, thinking Saxon best approximates what browsers do. I could be wrong. I note Xalan does not put in leading whitespace.

Comment: The processors in browsers do not serialize, instead they create an in-memory tree, so how do you know there is a blank line? Also, your assumption on Saxon is incorrect: it best approximates what the W3C standard requires, but no browser is even close to the XSLT standard...

Comment: Abel.. you are correct. I do not know, I'm taking a guess based on testing outside browser. Is there a way to view this in-memory tree?

Comment: There is, instead of doing rightclick > View Source, use rightclick > Inspect Element. This works in both Chrome and Firefox and will show you whatever got rendered.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your stylesheet with Saxon 6.5 and indeed, it outputs two blank lines, which are removed if you change the `xsl:output` to be without indentation and with xml declaration. However, I believe this to be a bug in Saxon 6.5 (a small one, as the whitespace is not significant).

Running it with other XSLT 1.0 processors show no whitepace. However, as said in my comment, the whitespace is insignificant, as browsers do not serialize anyway. (note: apparently, browsers do some kind of serialization, in the sense that they look to whether you use XML or HTML output).

I ran your example with Firefox and it "just works". Since your stylesheet does a simple copy of the XML, it shows just the text. If I change the `xsl:output` to HTML and add a few lines to be sure I am running it correctly (I added an `<h1>Hello</h1>`, it shows the HTML.

I'm not sure what you expect the browser to show, but my guess is not XML, but (X)HTML. XSLT 1.0 is not very good with XHTML (it is supported in XSLT 2.0, but that is not supported by browsers), but works fine with HTML.

I modified your stylesheet as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
            <html>
                <head />           
                <body>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />                    
                </body>
            </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title">
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="auth">
        <p>Author: <xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And in Firefox and Chrome it renders as follows:

[image]

Note (1): if you do not run it from a web server (either local or remote), it will not run in either Firefox or Chrome because of security restrictions.

Note (2): to view the rendered XML or HTML, use the Inspect Element feature of the developer tools of either Chrome or Firefox.

Note (3): you do not need to use the meta-tag, as the specification requires this meta tag to be output as soon as it recognizes that HTML is output.

Note (4) if you are unsure whether or not Firefox is loading your stylesheet correctly, have a look using Firebug, it should show something like this (mark the "200 OK"):

[image]

Comment: Still having trouble at my end. Are you running Noscript in Firefox? I am, and I wonder if that is interfering.

Comment: I only use an addblocker. Try turning of any and all extensions, run it from a web server and also make sure that the path is correct. I'm not sure, but strict security might mean that the path of the XSLT _must be relative and at the same level or deeper than the current file_.

Comment: @Paulb: I have added an extra note you may use to find out what is going wrong. If you _do_ see the XSLT loaded, then change some stuff in the XSLT (like outputting something different, as in my example above) to be sure it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transform to XHTML then you need to make sure you use the XHTML namespace for your result elements so put

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    version="1.0">
```

on your stylesheet, as otherwise with output method `xml` your elements in no namespace are not recognized as XHTML elements by Mozilla.

As your input `p` elements are also in no namespace you can not copy them through but have to write a template for them

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}"><!-- assumes you have the namespace declaration suggested above -->
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

and then use `<xsl:apply-templates select="//container-content/*"/>` instead of the `copy-of`. And in that case the `<xsl:template match="text()"/>` needs to be removed as otherwise the text of the transformed `p` elements would not show up.

Comment: +1, smart thinking, I didn't consider that in my answer, but indeed, this way it also works with `<xsl:output method="xml" />` (though "Inspect element" does not reveal it is XHTML). Also, in Firefox at least, with the `doc-type` added, it still won't render. But it is unnecessary anyway.